# Drop pod deviation above terrain

Tags: warhammer-40k

Assuming a drop pod place 2 inch away from a 6 inch wide impassible terrain (eg: river of lava).

Drop pod deviation says that it has to deviate 12 inches, in the direction that passes above said impassible terrain.

Does the drop pod stops deviation at the first boundary of the impassible terrain (and thus deviate only 2 inches), or does it cross/passes over the terrain since it can be placed freely on the other side of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop pods scatter 2D6 inches.  If the scatter does not take the model fully over a piece of impassible terrain, it stops at the edge of the impassible terrain.  If the model can be physically placed on the other side of the terrain moving no further than the rolled distance-even if that would put it off the edge of the playing area-it must then be placed on the other side of the terrain.

Sames goes for enemy units encountered by a drop pod scatter roll.